# valueChanges works after the second blur but not after the first one

Tags: angular

I would like to run my code as soon as the value of the input field has been changed.

```html
<input #firstName (blur)="_update('personal', 'firstName', firstName.value)" formControlName="firstName" type="text" matInput>
```

```js
private profileFormGroup = this.fb.group({
  firstName: ''
  },
  { updateOn: 'blur' }
  );

private _update(tableName: string, columnName: string, theValue: any) {
    console.log('Im blurred');
    this.profileFormGroup.get(columnName).valueChanges.subscribe(_ => {
      console.log('Im changed');      
    });
  }
```

My problem is, the first time when I change the value of the input field and blur it, I see the message *Im blurred* but not the message *Im changed*. The second time when I click again on the input field and change the value and blur it, then the message *Im changed* appears. Why doesn't it appear at the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register before the first update. For example in `ngOnInit`

```
sub: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    // ATTN: Do not forget about cleanup!!!
    this.sub = this.profileFormGroup.get(columnName).valueChanges.subscribe(_ => {
      console.log('Im changed');      
    });
}

private _update(tableName: string, columnName: string, theValue: any) {
    console.log('Blurry');
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without `ngOnInit()`? I need to run my own function because of its parameters. I have tried to declare a property (`valueChanged`) with the value of `this.profileFormGroup` in `ngOnInit()` and tried to use that property in my own function with `this.valueChanged.get(columnName).valueChanges.subscribe(_ => { ... ` but that does not work.

Comment: Either add one subscription to the entire group or loop over the columns `['col1', 'col2'].map(x => subscribe)`

Comment: In `ngOnInit()` I have used `this.profileFormGroup.get('firstName').valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
  if (x && !this.profileFormGroup.get('firstName').pristine) {
    this.valueChanged = true;
  }
});`. In my function I just check if `this.valueChanged` is true to do the rest. That works for me.